# Visual Studio 2010 make WebBrowser control use the webkit engine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, webkit, webbrowser-control

I am writing a c++ appliction in Visual Studio 2010 where I am creating some html and javascript code that has to be displayed in the gui to the user before they export it to a file. The built in WebBrowser control does a terrible job of displaying the css and javascript. Is there a way to make the WebBrowser control use the webkit engine?

Comment: C++ wouldn't be my first choice in languages for a web app but you can probably find a control more to your liking in a gui framework like Qt, wxWidgets, MFC, etc

Comment: Is there a way to embed a web control from qt in a c++ form?

Comment: You are not programming in the C++ language.  You are using C++/CLI, a very different language.  WebBrowser is married to Internet Explorer, if it looks bad in IE then it looks bad in WB.  You could upgrade IE.

Comment: Thats the thing man it looks like it should in IE but look like garbage in WB.

Comment: How did you get all the javascript and CSS in, if you dynamically generated it? My bets are that some CSS didn't make it.

Comment: If it looks right in IE but not in your browser control, you need to set FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION for your program.

Comment: The last comment was correct. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the WebBrowser control will embed IE only. However, you can get a WebKit control for .NET. A quick Google search revealed this:

http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Also, later versions of Internet Explorer have vastly improved CSS and JavaScript support to the extent that it is arguably on par with other browsers; if you haven't upgraded, perhaps that will help you.

Comment: You are using .NET, better get familiar with it.

Comment: So visual studio is referred to as .NET no matter what language?

Comment: No. Hans Passant is plain wrong here. Visual C++ is _not_ a .NET language. (C++/CLI is, but then you probably wouldn't be using the WebBrowser control).

Answer (score 1):

No, the WebBrowser control is pretty much defined as being the API of Internet Explorer. You *can* use the WebKit browser from your C++ code, but you should use its own API for that. See the "WebKitTools/WinLauncher" sample for details how to.